# Run Powerpoint in WP7 to edit a document

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on an app that needs to run powerpoint in windows phone 7 to let the user edit the document. The app connects to skydrive, so I have the file id, etc information for this document. How can I run powerpoint and open this document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i guess you would like to use the 'Office' app to do this, right?
Yet, this isn't possible, because Microsoft doesn't provide a 'Task' (like ConnectionSettingsTask e.g.) for this.

Comment: yes ,I want to use Office app, so basically user will click on the file from my app (my app gets the files from skydrive), and powerpoint will open to edit the file.

Comment: I would imagine if WP7 does not already have this functionality, it's for a reason. Something more complicated than just download and open on the phone.